# problems with users in vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd

I'm having trouble connecting to my vsftpd server, and I'm not sure what to do. I installed vsftpd, but when I try to connect using FTP and my IP address, it simply says "Connection Refused." I attempted to disable the firewall, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Do I need to create a user or perform any additional steps to get it working? I'm stuck and would appreciate any guidance on making this work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have problems in the past with this and i solved it, i'm gonna do a guide to help u step by step since the beginning .

1.-Install vsftpd

```
sudo apt install vsftpd
```

2.-If u need to change something edit the file vsftpd.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

3.-You can add or change some lines like the next ones inside the file.

```
listen_port=9999
local_root=/home/user/vsftpd
user_config_dirs=/etc/vsftpd/user_conf/
anon_umask= 077
local_umask= 077
ftpd_banner= Hey.
idle_session_timeout=600
```

4.-Now, you need to create the directory of your local root like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/user/vsftpd/{downloads,uploads}
```

5.-Then, you should create some users, in my case i will create the downloader, uploader and administrator one.

```
sudo useradd uploader -p /home/user/vsftpd/uploads
sudo passwd uploader
sudo useradd downloader -p /home/user/vsftpd/downloads
sudo passwd downloader
sudo useradd administrator -p /home/user/vsftpd
sudo passwd administrator
```

6.-Lets change the permission of the users in the directories, in my case i will give them this ones.

```
sudo chown -R uploader:uploader /home/user/vsftpd/uploads
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/vsftpd/uploads
sudo chmod -R u+w /home/user/vsftpd/uploads
sudo chown -R downloader:downloader /home/user/vsftpd/downloads
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/vsftpd/downloads
sudo chmod -R u-w /home/user/vsftpd/downloads
sudo chown -R admin:admin /home/user/vsftpd
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/vsftpd
```

7.-You can create a directory to users configuration.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/vsftpd/user_conf
```

and give it some users directives.

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd/user_conf/uploader
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd/user_conf/downloader
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd/user_conf/admin
```

8.-In my case this files containe :

uploader

```
write_enable=YES
download_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=YES
```

downloader

```
write_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=YES
```

admin

```
write_enable=YES
anon_world_readable_only=NO
```

9.-If you still have some problems try to disable your firewall with `sudo ufw disable` try to change some permissions on previously directories like `sudo chmod 777 /home/user/...` if the directories are unreachable, remember try to connect like `ftp ip port` separate with spaces, you can also restart vsftpd like `sudo systemctl restart vsftpd`